# Two datetimepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap datetimepickers to input start and end datetimes.

Is there any way to make sure/validate that the end datetimepicker is not before the start datatimepicker?

```
    $('#start').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: date 
    })

    $('#end').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: date 
    })
```

Comment: just check if the input field is not empty..

Comment: You need to use the datetimepicker events to set the min/max dates. Exactly how will depend on the library you are using. [Here's one example](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers).

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest this instead of bootstrap, look here and just replace the min option
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

$('#DatePicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker : false,
    format : 'd.m.Y',
    minDate : '-1969/12/31'
})

You have to set a min date, it should be dinamically set that way it will work with different dates

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it when the end date is set:

```
$('#end').change(function(){
    if(this.val() != ""){
        var start_date = $('#start').val();
        var end_date = $('#end').val();

        if(start_date <= end_date){
            //After
        }else{
            //Before
        }
    }
});
```

Or at the form submission:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    var start_date = $('#start').val();
    var end_date = $('#end').val();

    if(start_date <= end_date){
        //After
    }else{
        //Before
    }

});
```

Comment: It's more about checking the time. For example, if I select 5/04/2015 9:00 in start, then select 5/04/2015 8.00 in the end it shouldn't let me..