# DateTimePicker loaded with two times when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am using [DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452557/two-datetimepickers) for two time inputs in my modal window, i.e. `Start Time` and `End Time`. It works fine in loading the `AJAX`-retrieved values and changing the times. When I click the time input, there are always two times highlighted/selected like the screenshot below. I want it to only highlight one time but can't figure out how. Please kindly help. My codes are listed below.
[image]

#### Initializing the time control

```js
$('#start_time_id').datetimepicker({
      timepicker: true,
      datepicker: false,
      opened: false,
      format: 'H:i:s',
      allowTimes: ['07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30','09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30',
                   '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30','13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30',
                   '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30','17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30',
                   '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30','21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00'],
      onSelectTime: function (time, $input) {
        // hack to prevent non-zero values for seconds
        let t = new Date(time)
        let newTime = ''
        let hours = t.getHours()
        newTime = hours.toString()
        if (hours < 10) {
          newTime = '0' + newTime
        }
        newTime += ':'
        let minutes = t.getMinutes()
        if (minutes < 10) {
          newTime += '0'
        }
        newTime += (minutes.toString() + ':00')
        $input.val(newTime)
      }
    })
```

#### Setting the time control's value

```js
$("#start_time_id").val("18:00:00")
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"in loading the AJAX-retrieved values"* maybe in the ajax return, could be times highlighted?

Comment: I don't think the times are highlighted. The AJAX data can be seen in https://run.mocky.io/v3/f869037c-1ac6-45c8-9fd4-b9a577fe6b0f